# HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found on action in controller. MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an action I made myself in the controller which returns all blogs of a certain category

```
[Route("Blog/CategoryBlogs/{id}")]
public ActionResult CategoryBlogs(string id)
{ 
    CategoryOperations co = new CategoryOperations();
    category c = co.GetCategory(id);

    return View(db.blogs.Where(x => x.categoryId == c.Id).ToList());
}
```

I try to pass the parameter from my index page like this

```
<a href='@Url.Action("CategoryBlogs","Blog",new { id = "MVC.Net" })'>MVC.Net</a>
```

However I Always get **HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found**. Somehow when I write link without the parameter it enters the method.

Link Generated: `/Blog/CategoryBlogs/MVC.Net`

Comment: Since you are generating a link, can you show what the generated HTML is?

Comment: Done :) Thanks for the suggestion  @Philippe

Comment: Does it work if you do not have a dot `.` in the value of the `id` parameter? E.g. "MVCNet" instead of "MVC.Net".

Comment: Yes @GeorgPatscheider